# \listoffixmes gives an error with revtex4

Tags: table-of-contents, revtex, fixme

I get the error

```
! Illegal unit of measure (mu inserted).
```

when I try to include `\listoffixmes` in a `revtex4` document. I think that it has something to do with `revtex4` redefining the way to make table of contents, but I do not know enough LaTeX to know how to fix it.

This code should reproduce the problem:

```
\documentclass{revtex4}
\usepackage[draft]{fixme}

\begin{document}

\listoffixmes

Some text.\fxnote{A short note}

\end{document}
```

Is there a simple way to solve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `fixme` package assumes `\@dotsep` just expands to a decimal number, while `revtex4` expects it to contain a dimension. A quick fix is to provide a redefinition as requested, in a group so the redefinition is not propagated; I use the hooks `fixme` executes before and after inputting the `.lox` file.

```
\documentclass{revtex4}
\usepackage[draft]{fixme}

\makeatletter
\def\@lox@prtc{\section*{\@fxlistfixmename}\begingroup\def\@dotsep{4.5}}
\def\@lox@psttc{\endgroup}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\listoffixmes

Some text.\fxnote{A short note}

\end{document}
```

The fix works also with `revtex4-1`

Comment: This also works for revtex4-2, although the error message seems to be different (`Missing control sequence inserted`; `\inaccessible`; `You can't use `\lastskip' in horizontal mode`, ...)